# HowTo Compile a 32-bit Application Using gcc On the 64-bit MacBook Terminal

Tags: macos, assembly, i386

So I'm trying to run a .s file and every time I do using the command line:
gcc -m32 -o Compute32 Compute.s
I'm given this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
  "printf", referenced from:
      main in Compute-f6f555.o
  "scanf", referenced from:
      main in Compute-f6f555.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation
```

Can anyone advise me on the next step?

Comment: Please show us your `Compute.s`.

Comment: Looks like your environment uses a leading underscore on symbols, so it's looking for `_main` when you probably have `main`. Also, you reference `printf` and `scanf` without an underscore too.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess since you didn't show me your `Compute.s`, but I guess your problem is that on OS X, all C functions are prefixed with an underscore in assembly. So if you change your `main` to `_main` and likewise `printf` to `_printf`, etc. your problem should be resolved.